# R: How to create/label ranges for a variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, "Labeled_Data". One of the variable inside this dataframe is called "PCT_Stock_MF_1". This variable, PCT_Stock_MF_1 has values of 0-100 that I want to use, and values 998 and 999 that I want to ignore. I want to group together the values in groups of: 0-19, 20-49, 50-74, and 75-100.

I then want to label these groups as "low risk" (0:19), "some risk" (20-49), "high risk" (50-74), and "substantial risk" (75-100).

I want to break these into groups so that I can run regressions on this variable with other variables in the original "Labeled_Data" data frame.

If it makes my description of "PCT_Stocks_MF_1" clearer, here is a description of the variable:

> describe(PCT_Stocks_MF_1)
>   PCT_Stocks_MF_1 : PERCENT IN STOCK OR MUTUAL FUND -1 
>         n missing  unique    Info    Mean     .05     .10     .25 
>      5121   10879      45    0.92   229.4      30      50      70 
>       .50     .75     .90     .95 
>       100     100     998     998

lowest :   1   2   3   4   5, highest:  98  99 100 998 999

> class(PCT_Stocks_MF_1)
>   [1] "labelled" "integer"

Thanks for any help possible

Comment: Take a look at the `cut` function, it has got `breaks` and `labels` as you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Example with cut():

```
# Generate some sample data
values <- as.integer(c(runif(48, 0, 100), 998, 999))

# Filter out values greater than 100
results <- data.frame(values=values[values<=101])

# Assign risk category
results$risk <- cut(results$values, c(0, 19, 49, 74, 100), 
                    labels=c("Low", "Some", "High", "Substantial" ), include.lowest=T)
```

To run regressions (or call other functions) by group, check out the `dplyr` package.